# Creating new instance of the same class as an existing instance, without using eval()

Tags: javascript, typescript, constructor, eval

I have an instance `sampleInstance` of an unknown class and I need to create a second instance of the same class. Here's what I am doing right now:

1. I look up the class name with `sampleInstance.constructor.name`.
2. Next, I use `` eval(`new ${sampleInstance.constructor.name}()`) `` to create a new instance of the same class.

The code below works fine:

```ts
class sampleClass_A { name = "Archimedes";}
class sampleClass_B { name = "Pythagoras";}

let sampleInstance = new sampleClass_A();

// later, in another part of the code, I don't know the constructor of sampleInstance anymore
let constructorName = sampleInstance.constructor.name
let newInstanceOfTheSameClass = eval(`new ${constructorName}()`); // how to do without eval()???
console.log(newInstanceOfTheSameClass .name); // "Archimedes"
```

But I'd rather not use `eval()`. What's a cleaner alternative?

(I cannot use `window[constructorName]` because this code will not run in a browser in the general case. (Not even sure if it would work in a browser.))

Comment: I'm wondering why you're even considering `eval` over something like `new sampleInstance.constructor()` (do you usually need to get the *name* of a value and then `eval` it to get the value back again?).  Just using `sampleInstance.constructor` as a constructor will work at runtime (TS doesn't have strongly typed constructors so you'd need to use a type assertion to prevent a compiler error).  Like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mqyQkm) shows.  Does that fully address the question?  If not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using typescript, as seen in this instance code

```
class sampleClass_A { name = "Archimedes";}
```

I created a fiddle for you:

```
class sampleClass_A { name = "Archimedes";}
class sampleClass_B { name = "Pythagoras";}

let sampleInstance = new sampleClass_A();

// later, in another part of the code, I don't know the constructor of sampleInstance anymore
//let constructorName = sampleInstance.constructor.name;
//let newInstanceOfTheSameClass = eval(`new ${constructorName}()`); // how to do without eval()???

let newInstanceOfTheSameClass = new sampleInstance.constructor();
console.log(newInstanceOfTheSameClass .name); // "Archimedes"
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t9gdasur/

Let me know if it works. if not, I'll try something else.

Answer (score 1):

Call the constructor directly !

```
const aCopy = new (sampleInstance.constructor as any)();
console.log(aCopy);
```

The only downside I see is that the constructor is not type, so you'll have to cast it and the returned value won't be typed.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEFgtgBxAUwMLigfQILQN7QB2CK0AvNAEQ4BOwAFgJbwoAmKEVA3AL4BQoSDDhJUGYVgBCBYqQrUACgE8ALgzABzAPa1IPAf1SrYCZCgCSRCKrBFgZSkRQB3U2PSYIuABQBKbn4g4G1rEzA0bURlBWc3H1FzKxs7BwA6ELDaAFdgVV1oSEKiZT9-QMyIbVQ0kG1NHwio5TSSVgCgA)

Answer (score 1):

> 1- Get a reference to the constructor function of the existing
> instance using its prototype.
>
> 2- Use the retrieved constructor to create a new instance of the same
> class.

```
class sampleClass_A { name = "Archimedes"; }
class sampleClass_B { name = "Pythagoras"; }

let sampleInstance = new sampleClass_A();

// Step 1: Retrieve the constructor
const constructor = sampleInstance.__proto__.constructor;

// Step 2: Create a new instance
let newInstanceOfTheSameClass = new constructor();

console.log(newInstanceOfTheSameClass.name); // "Archimedes"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).